# jQuery cross-browser issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I have this code that works great in all browsers but not IE6, and I have no idea why, can anyone shed any light on this?

```
$("#handle").toggle(    
    function () {
        $('#login').animate({
            marginTop: '0',
        }, 1000);
        $("#handle").addClass('opened');
        return false;
    }, 
    function () {
        $('#login').animate({
            marginTop: '-280',
        }, 1000);
        $("#handle").removeClass('opened');
        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: IE6 just loads with errors on page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have trailing commas in the object literals passed to `animate()`. IE does not support this. This should work:

```
$('#login').animate({
  marginTop: '0' //No comma, can you see it?
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I guess I can.

**The EVIL COMMA has GOT you !!**

```
marginTop: '0',  // remove comma
```

and

```
marginTop: '-280', // remove comma
```

Trailing commas are a big NoNo in IE's.

Answer (score 1):

Also shouldn't it be

```
"-280px" // added "px"
```